# UITextView Data Selectors Without User Interaction Enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITableView` of custom cells that contain a `UITextView`.
I want the `UITextView` to have data detectors (so that you can tap on URLs), however, I also want the user to be able to tap on the table view cell to select it. With the data dectors, I must have user interaction enabled, but to select the cell when tapping on the `UITextView`, I must have it disabled.

Is there any easy way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UITableViewCellAccessory` (checkmark, disclosure indicator or others) to your cells. Then use the method `tableView: accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` in order to detect click on the accessory.